# getting java.lang.ClassCastException: [Ljava.lang.Integer; cannot be cast to [I

Tags: reflection, classcastexception

Try to get a method return type int array and getting casting error
for(String s:oldOfferList)
        {
            LOGGER.log(Level.FINE, "Method name"+s);

```
        Method getNameMethod = old_offer2.getClass().getMethod(s);
        if(getNameMethod.getName().equals("getLevelId"))
        {
             @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
              int[] oldLevelids =  (int[]) getNameMethod.invoke(old_offer2);
             @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
              int[] newMethodsval =  (int[]) getNameMethod.invoke(current_offer2);
              if( !Arrays.equals(oldLevelids, newMethodsval)){
              LOGGER.log(Level.FINE," oldLevelids not equals to newMethodsval : "  
                       ); 
              DiffPropValuesEntity dpv=new DiffPropValuesEntity(getNameMethod.getName().toString(),Arrays.toString(oldLevelids).replaceAll("\\s+", ""),Arrays.toString(newMethodsval).replaceAll("\\s+", ""));
                listDiffPropValuesEntity.add(dpv);
              }else {
                  LOGGER.log(Level.FINE," oldLevelids  equals to newMethodsval : "  );

              }
         continue;
        }
```

Comment: It means, you are trying to cast `Integer[]` to `int[]`. Given that there are `(int[])` casts in your code, this looks plausible. When the method’s actual return type is `Integer[]`, you can’t cast it to `int[]`.

Comment: Yes you are right , but why its not possible, whereas can cast single element of an array

Comment: Casting a single `Integer` to `int` is syntactic sugar (unboxing) for calling `intValue()` on the `Integer` object to get the actual `int` value. In fact, in most contexts you don’t even need the cast for this conversion. But there is no syntactic sugar for doing this with all elements of an array and copying the results into a newly created array.